# What is the cache size of useCallback and useMemo react hook and why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm looking at React source [code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js) and specifically at `useCallback` implementation. As far as I understand the cache size of `useCallback` is one. In `mountCallback` we initialize `hook.memoizedState` to an array where the first element is the `callback` - the first parameter to `useCallback`. In `updateCallback` if the dependencies didn't change then we return the first element of the `hook.memoizedState` array. Because the `callback`'s reference didn't change there will not be a re-rendering. Conversely, if the dependencies changed and we set the first element of `hook.memoizedState` array to the `callback` parameter of `updateCallback` then `callback`'s reference will change (because function object parameters always have a new value), therefore triggering re-rendering.

So caching in `useCallback` is based on the `callback`'s reference. Is my understanding correct?

```
function mountCallback<T>(callback: T, deps: Array<mixed> | void | null): T {
  const hook = mountWorkInProgressHook();
  const nextDeps = deps === undefined ? null : deps;
  hook.memoizedState = [callback, nextDeps];
  return callback;
}

function updateCallback<T>(callback: T, deps: Array<mixed> | void | null): T {
  const hook = updateWorkInProgressHook();
  const nextDeps = deps === undefined ? null : deps;
  const prevState = hook.memoizedState;
  if (prevState !== null) {
    if (nextDeps !== null) {
      const prevDeps: Array<mixed> | null = prevState[1];
      if (areHookInputsEqual(nextDeps, prevDeps)) {
        return prevState[0];
      }
    }
  }
  hook.memoizedState = [callback, nextDeps];
  return callback;
}
```

Comment: not sure I understand what you are asking us...would you kindly edit your question and make it specific?

Comment: @Peter I think the question is very precise. Where do you find ambiguity in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caches the `callback` itself plus the dependent values you passed as the second argument. At any point in time it holds **one** `callback` reference and **one** array of dependent values.

It needs the dependent values to check if it should create a new callback reference or not.